# OpenLayers 3 zoom to boundary box

Tags: javascript, zooming, openlayers-3

I tried to zoom to all points on map. I have array of GPS (lon,lat) coords, makes extent and I tried to zoom. But map is zoomed outside of extent. How can I do that? I tried this code:

```
var devices = document.querySelectorAll(".device_icon");
var coords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    var lon = devices[i].getAttribute("data-lon");
    var lat = devices[i].getAttribute("data-lat");

    coords.push([lon, lat]);
}
var ex = ol.extent.boundingExtent(coords);
var areaExtent = ol.extent.applyTransform(ex, ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

map.getView().fitExtent(areaExtent, map.getSize());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. The problem is in type of lon, lat. I had to change this line

```
coords.push([lon, lat]);
```

to line

```
coords.push([parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat)]);
```

Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar code in my project, but i'm using this function to transform the extent:

```
var areaextent = ol.proj.transformExtent(ex, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
```

I dont know if the function or the target-projection makes the difference. Just try ;)

Comment: I tried this, but same result :(.
My coords in "ex" are = [14.82166667,49.4809083,15.86349,50.28216667]